# How to Print some WordPress Cateogries?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've the following code in attempt to print the second top category and the category of a search result:

```
$category = get_the_terms( $post_id , 'manualknowledgebasecat');
$number =  $category[0] -> term_id;
echo get_category_parents( $numero, true, ' &raquo; ' );
```

The previous code print the complete list of categories, but I only want it to print the second category and the current category. For example: If a search result has this categories: `Products >> NameOfTheProduct >> Manual >> Configurations`
I just want to print the `NameOfTheProduct` and `Configurations`. How can I get to do that ?

Thank you for you replies in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: $number != $numero..

Comment: explode the string to array and get your required value by key